# Rigidbody unity

Tags: c#, unity3d

Можно ли каким-либо способом избежать взаимодействия двух rigidbody при их столкновении, при этом не нарушая работу их функций?

Comment: [Layer-based collision detection](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/LayerBasedCollision.html)

Comment: @Yaroslav это интересное решение, но к сожалению оно мне не подходит. Желательно оставить коллизию объектов друг с другом, но чтобы коллизия никак не влияла на rigidbody (т.е. отталкивание объектов при столкновение), который висит на каждом из этих объектов и движется за счет него. Это кажется невозможным...

Comment: Коллизия это и есть влияние тел друг на друга, хотеть одного без другого... отрезвей и проспись, а уже потом вопрос задавай.

Answer (score 1):

Не очень понятен твой вопрос, но я понял его так:

Ты хочешь, чтобы у rigidbody были коллайдеры, но при этом они ни во что не врезались и чтобы у них были такие параметры, как гравитация и тому подобное от rigidbody.

В общем ты можешь попробовать поставить галочку IsTrigger у коллайдера объекта, которому хочешь выключить коллизию.

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider-isTrigger.html

> Триггер (IsTrigger) не регистрирует столкновение с входящим твердым телом. Вместо этого он отправляет сообщения OnTriggerEnter, OnTriggerExit и OnTriggerStay, когда твердое тело входит в триггерный объем или выходит из него.

На сообщения OnTriggerEnter, OnTriggerExit и OnTriggerStay *пока* можешь не обращать внимания, ведь тебе важнее сейчас отключение коллизии.